# How to correctly order files based on the filename

Tags: c#, winforms

I use this function:

```
files = Directory.GetFiles(tbDirectory.Text).ToArray();
```

and my files saved in this order:

```
Text.txt
Text_10.txt
Text_2.txt
...
Text_9.txt
```

I want them to be sorted like windows does:

```
Text.txt
Text_2.txt
...
Text_9.txt
Text_10.txt
```

How I can do that?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518/natural-sorting-algorithm or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389929/how-can-i-use-c-sharp-to-sort-values-numerically. even http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217029/sort-string-list-with-numeric-values or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788227/sorting-a-list-of-strings-numerically-1-2-9-10-instead-of-1-10-2

Comment: deleting my answer because I see it does not result in your natural order sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on  Andrey Shchekin answer you just need to make a class like this:

```
internal class FileNameComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string psz1, string psz2);

    public int Compare(string a, string b)
    {
        return StrCmpLogicalW(a, b);
    }
}
```

And then to use this comparer:

```
files = Directory.GetFiles(tbDirectory.Text).OrderBy(file => file, new FileNameComparer()).ToArray();
```

Comment: All the above duplicates answers will not help beginners in C#, my code is clear and simple for everyone.

Comment: You've chosen to use your own answer only because it's a copy/paste solution for you. The above answer is the same without providing unneeded information. You've only answered 2 questions, both are your own, and neither was a worthwhile answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to sort them in the same way as Windows, you can use this function for comparison:

```
[DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string psz1, string psz2);
```

You then can define your implementation of `IComparer<string>` that would use this function.

Comment: Can you please tell me where to add this code?

Comment: Normally P/Invoke functions are defined in an internal static class. As for calling it, the best way is to define your own `IComparer<string>`.